# is this switch case correct?

Tags: java

```
public class SwitchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(“value = “ + switchIt(4));
    }
    public static int switchIt(int x) {
        int j = 1;
        switch (x) {
            case 1: j++;
            case 2: j++;
            case 3: j++;
            case 4: j++;
            case 5: j++;
            default: j++;
        }
        return j + x;
    }
}
```

why above code print 8 instead of 6 ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 6?

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, the output is correct, it's doing exactly what you _told_ it to do. Whether that's what you _intended_ it to do is another matter but I'd consider that a bug in your grey matter rather than a bug in the program :-)

Answer (score 4):

when you didnt use break, it continues to other cases, at first j is 1  :

```
case 4: j++; // j became 2
case 5: j++; // j became 3
default: j++; // j became 4
```

if you want the output of your code be 6 you could change your code like this:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1: j++;
        break;
    case 2: j++;
        break;
    case 3: j++;
        break;
    case 4: j++;
        break;
    case 5: j++;
        break;
    default: j++;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the sloppy code formatting :-) in the second code snippet, this appears to be the correct answer.